# Azure Functions Runtime v3 Middleware

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Is there a way to access the request and response object in an azure middle ware.

Using a tutorial for a logging middleware I already got this far:

```
public class ExceptionLoggingMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        try
        {
            // Code before function execution here
            await next(context);
            // Code after function execution here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var log = context.GetLogger<ExceptionLoggingMiddleware>();
            log.LogWarning(ex, string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

but I want to access the response and request object too. Like status code, body parameters, query parameters etc. Is this possible?

Comment: HTTP bindings are just *one* kind of functions binding. This kind of worker middleware is for *any* kind of function. I'm not sure if AF has HTTP-specific middleware, but I rather doubt it. So you'd need to look at the AF HTTP binding code and determine how it attaches request/response objects to `FunctionContext`, and access them the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. There is an IMiddleware interface which provides access to these objects. I'll try to work with that.

Comment: You can inject IHttpContextAccessor. Make sure to declare dependency registration via Startup. Example - https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Functions/Startup.cs

Comment: I found the context accessor, yet I am not quiet sure how to access it in a middleware. I will dig further into that. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: MIddleware also support DI. So you can inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` in `ExceptionLoggingMiddleware` constructor.

Comment: Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the release of [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker 1.18](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker) this is now directly supported.

Here's an example of a HTTP Request middleware

```
internal sealed class StampHttpHeaderMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var requestData = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();

        string correlationId;
        if (requestData!.Headers.TryGetValues("x-correlationId", out var values))
        {
            correlationId = values.First();
        }
        else
        {
            correlationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        await next(context);

        context.GetHttpResponseData()?.Headers.Add("x-correlationId", correlationId);
    }
}
```

and response

```
public class CustomMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var response = context.GetHttpResponseData();

        // do something with response

        await next(context);
    }
}
```

the binding is performed during start up

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(workerApplication =>
    {
        // Register our custom middlewares with the worker

        workerApplication.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>();

        workerApplication.UseMiddleware<CustomMiddleware>();

        workerApplication.UseWhen<StampHttpHeaderMiddleware>((context) =>
        {
            // We want to use this middleware only for http trigger invocations.
            return context.FunctionDefinition.InputBindings.Values
                          .First(a => a.Type.EndsWith("Trigger")).Type == "httpTrigger";
        });
    })
    .Build();
```

These examples are drawn from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#middleware), there is also an [example project](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/tree/main/samples/CustomMiddleware)

Answer (score 3):

While there is no direct way to do this, but **there is a workaround for accessing `HttpRequestData`** (*Not the best solution but it should work until there is a fix.*):

```
public static class FunctionContextExtensions
{
    public static HttpRequestData GetHttpRequestData(this FunctionContext functionContext)
    {
        try
        {
            KeyValuePair<Type, object> keyValuePair = functionContext.Features.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Key.Name == "IFunctionBindingsFeature");
            object functionBindingsFeature = keyValuePair.Value;
            Type type = functionBindingsFeature.GetType();
            var inputData = type.GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name == "InputData").GetValue(functionBindingsFeature) as IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>;
            return inputData?.Values.SingleOrDefault(o => o is HttpRequestData) as HttpRequestData;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
public class CustomMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        HttpRequestData httpRequestData = context.GetHttpRequestData();

        // do something with httpRequestData

        await next(context);
    }
}
```

Check out [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/414#issuecomment-828810635) for more details.

**For `Http Response`, there is no workaround AFAIK.** Further, check out [GH Issue#530](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/530), that says that documentation for this will be added soon. *This capability looks like a popular demand and expected to be fixed soon (at the time of writing this).*

Comment: I am going to try your solution. Thank you.

Comment: I will do that. No worries. I just need time to implement it ;)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I need the response as well to finish what I intent to do. Therefore, while this solution works for the HttpRequestData, its not usable for me regarding this issue.

Comment: For HttpResponseData, there is no workaround to manipulate it as of now (if you are asking this).

Comment: No, not asking about manipulating it, rather collecting it before its getting send back to the client

Comment: We cannot AFAIK.

Comment: Hey, If I am trying to fetch requestData using GetHttpRequestData in invoke (as suggested) then after it in next(context) my req.body is going null, can anyone help me with why is this happening ?