# How can I set up a middleware in a .NET Core 3.1 Azure Functions project? trying to dependency inject an external service that requires middleware

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, startup, asp.net-core-3.1

As the title says,

How can I set up a middleware in a .NET Core 3.1 Azure Functions project? trying to dependency inject an external service that requires middleware.

First off, there are some problems here.

The Function app you create in Visual Studio 19, doesn't contain a Startup.cs class.

So we have to create this manually. Then there's a problem that it's not behaving like a real Startup class. It needs to inherit FunctionsStartup.

This is achieved by adding this line of code before the namespace first for some reason.

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(test_project.Startup))]
```

Then we need to inherit **FunctionsStartup** and then implement it.

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{            
}
```

So after this, we are able to Add stuff like Singleton or external service like so,

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Services.AddSomeExternalService();    

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<SomeOtherStuff>(
        new SomeOtherStuff(config, env_SomeOtherStuff));
}
```

But now my real problem starts. We need to add middleware for some functionality to work in the external service.

Usually, you can do this in a **web applications** (not function app) like so,

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSomeExternalServiceMiddleware();
}
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to do this in a function app with core 3.1

maybe it's not implemented the same way, I don't know why.

Is there a workaround for this sort of problem?

Comment: You are correct in that Function apps and web apps implement different frameworks. The middleware concept as known in web application are not built in to functions platform.

Comment: This is most likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Nkosi: how is this an XY problem. Can you elaborate, or be more specific, thanks

Comment: The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y (middleware in Functions app) would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.

Comment: Not sure if you read the whole question. In the title, I'm asking about how to set up a middleware. In the body I'm trying to show what I have tried. and at the bottom of the body, I'm showing how one usually adds middleware in a core web-app. But similar does not work in a func-app.

Comment: What @Nkosi is trying to say is that you didn't describe what you are trying to implement using middleware. Since middleware is not something that is built in, describing what it is you are trying to achieve (concrete example) allows others to supply you with alternatives that might effectively solve the problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. Don't know how this is important, because another middleware one might want to add might have the same problem. Anyhow, I'm trying to use a logging service called Rollbar.
Here's their page https://docs.rollbar.com/docs
Not much is documented on how to use this with a function app.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this but there is a [proposed feature](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/414) that you can refer to.

More References :

1. [Dependency Injection in Azure Functions with C# (twilio.com)](https://www.twilio.com/blog/draft-dependency-injection-in-azure-functions-with-csharp)
2. [c# - Azure Functions Runtime v3 Middleware - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68603349/azure-functions-runtime-v3-middleware)
3. [Be able to overwrite http response in IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware · Issue #530 · Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/530)