# Azure Functions Filters + Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I'm creating a filter in my azure functions to do an http log.

My filter, should record the log in a repository.

As I cannot inject my repository into a filter or instantiate my repository directly, what should I do?

```
    public class MyCustomAttribute : FunctionInvocationFilterAttribute
    {

        private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;

        /// <summary>
        /// This dont work! I can't inject a dependency in a Filter!!
        /// </summary>
        public HttpLogAttribute(IMyRepository myRepository)
        {
            _myRepository = myRepository;
        }


        public override Task OnExecutedAsync(FunctionExecutedContext executedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            var myData = new MyData();
            ...
            ...
            _myRepository.Add(myData);

            return base.OnExecutedAsync(executedContext, cancellationToken);

        } //OnExecutedAsync

    } //class
```

Comment: AFAIK, the dependency injection for function invocation filters is not implemented yet. Even the function filters are still in preview, even though many expressed their [desire](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1284) for it to be 'out of preview'. Look at `middleware`, probably that is the forward direction, I am not sure.

Comment: Azure Functions [middleware](https://www.re-mark-able.net/blogs/2021/05/09/azure-functions-middleware.html), and see the links in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68603349/azure-functions-runtime-v3-middleware)

Comment: If you made your Azure function run `out-of-process`, then you can have better control on DI, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#start-up-and-configuration)

Comment: Using middleware, I can't access response (like Status Code).